# Dynamicaly change label of dropdown / flutter

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I use dropdown_search 1.0.4
https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search

```
DropdownSearch<String>(
    mode: Mode.MENU,
    showSelectedItem: true,
    items: ["Brazil", "Italia (Disabled)", "Tunisia", 'Canada'],
    label: "Please Select",
    hint: "country in menu mode",
    popupItemDisabled: (String s) => s.startsWith('I'),
    onChanged: print,
    selectedItem: "Brazil"),
```

When u start project you can see "Please Select" label. Then if you choose Brazil you see "Brazil" as selected. My question is - is there any way to change that from selected Brazil back to "Please Select" somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

To set the value to the previous state i.e, `Please Select`

Set the value of your variable to `null`

This will let the dropdown selector know, that there is no active/selected value and display the `hint text`